# I can't count results in my database with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo, count

I have this error has shown:
Notice: Undefined variable: conn in D:\xampp\htdocs\website\core\functions\users.php on line 4

Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on null in D:\xampp\htdocs\website\core\functions\users.php on line 4

this is connect database

connect.php

```
<?php 
$servername = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$passwd = "";
$dbname = "userdata";
try {
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $user, $passwd);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

} catch (PDOException $exc) {
die($exc->getMessage());
}
?>
```

and in this part I have the problem

users.php

```
    <?php 
    function user_exists($username){
        $sql ="SELECT COUNT('id') FROM users where username = '$username'";
        $query = $conn->query($sql);
        $result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if(count($result)){
            $res = 0;
        }else {
            $res = 1;
        }
        return $res;
    }
    ?>
```

and this where I connected users.php with connect.php

init.php

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    require 'database/connect.php';
    require 'functions/users.php';
    require 'functions/general.php';

    $errors = array();
    ?>
```

Comment: I think you are new to pdo then insteading of learning pdo learn redbeanphp . it will remove all your hassle.

Comment: You have a scope problem.  Inside of your function, you don't have access to `$conn`.  Add `global $conn;` at the beginning of the function, and you will have access to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) problem.

Because `$conn` is set / declared outside of your function, you do not have access to it *inside* of your function.

Modify your function as follows:

```
function user_exists($username){
    // This gets you access to the $conn variable inside the function.
    global $conn;
    $sql ="SELECT COUNT('id') FROM users where username = '$username'";
    $query = $conn->query($sql);
    $result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if(count($result)){
        $res = 0;
    }else {
        $res = 1;
    }
    return $res;
}
```